# Laravel count query

Tags: laravel, count

Something is strange.I try to check if query gives at least one object in collection. It has always worked, but now, it does not anymore.

```
$myObj = User::whereRaw("lower(name) = '".strtolower(trim("toto"))."'");
if ( $myObj->count() > 0) {
   \Log::info( "Good" );
}
```

Code stops working. but if I add:

```
$myObj = User::whereRaw("lower(name) = '".strtolower(trim("toto"))."'");
\Log::info( $myObj->count() );
if ( $myObj->count() > 0) {
    \Log::info( "Good" );
}
```

it displays the number of objects returned by query, before breaking the code.

What is wrong, please?

Comment: Please post code inside the if statement

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, but I would highly recommend you don't do this. Running `->count()` twice will run a MySQL `SELECT COUNT(*)...` statement twice. If you want to get the collection and then count then you need to do `->get()` after the `whereRaw`, in which case `count()` would be the collection count which is a constant time operation

Comment: It is strange, but for the moment, I change to "empty" method. but I would like to understand what is wrong, and why I am getting this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, you omit the method `get()` to fetch all records, maybe it could be:

```
$myObj = User::whereRaw("lower(name) = '".strtolower(trim("toto"))."'")->get();
```

Comment: Yes that is the answer. I noticed it few minutes after my post, but I forget to put it here. Thanks @eduardo. Hope this could help other laravel developers if they miss it like me. thanks to everyone